# XNA/HLSL Heightmap from VertexShader

Tags: xna, hlsl

Anyone can tell why i get this Error:

**The current vertex declaration does not include all the elements required by the current vertex shader. TextureCoordinate0 is missing.**

With the standard Vertex Shader, everything is fine.

**Here is my Shader File:**

```
float4x4 World; 
float4x4 View; 
float4x4 Projection; 
float4 color; 
float seaLevel; 
texture myTexture; 
float maxHeight = 128; 
float height; 


sampler2D mySampler = sampler_state 
{ 
Texture = <myTexture>; 
MinFilter = Point; 
MagFilter = Point; 
MipFilter = Point; 
AddressU = Clamp; 
AddressV = Clamp; 
}; 

struct VertexShaderInput 
{ 
float4 Position : POSITION0; 
}; 
struct VertexShaderOutput 
{ 
float4 Position : POSITION0; 
}; 


struct VS_INPUT 
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float4 uv : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
     float4 position  : POSITION;
     float4 uv : TEXCOORD0;
     float4 worldPos : TEXCOORD1;
};


VS_OUTPUT Transform(VS_INPUT In)
{
      VS_OUTPUT Out = (VS_OUTPUT)0;    
      float4x4 viewProj = mul(View, Projection);
      float4x4 worldViewProj= mul(World, viewProj);
      float height = tex2Dlod ( mySampler, float4(In.uv.xy , 0 , 0 ) );
      In.position.y = height * maxHeight;
      Out.worldPos = mul(In.position, World);
      Out.position = mul( In.position , worldViewProj);
      Out.uv = In.uv;
      return Out;
}


VertexShaderOutput VertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderInput input) 
{ 

    VertexShaderOutput output; 

    float4 worldPosition = mul(input.Position, World); 



    worldPosition = float4(normalize(worldPosition.xyz) * seaLevel, 1); 

    float4 viewPosition = mul(worldPosition, View); 
    output.Position = mul(viewPosition, Projection); 

    return output; 
} 




float4 PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0 
{ 

return color; 
} 

technique Technique1 
{ 
pass Pass1 
{ 


VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 Transform(); 
PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PixelShaderFunction(); 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The model that your are trying to draw has vertex that no contains texture coordinates.

Your vertex shader needs a texture coordinate to work, as seen in the struct that is used by the vertex shader specified in your technique.

```
struct VS_INPUT 
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float4 uv : TEXCOORD0;
};

technique Technique1 
{ 
    pass Pass1 
    {     
        VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 Transform();
```

So, you have two choices:

1) Remove "uv" from VS_INPUT

2) Add the texture coordiante field to the vertex used by your model.

Answer (score 0):

I solved same problem by opening the model in 3D Studio Max, adding "UVM Map" modifier and exporting back. Not a satisfying solution but worked for me.